# How to connect a Firebird data base with Knime?

Tags: firebird, knime, jaybird

I need connect my Firebird data base (.IDB) in KNIME. I used Database Connector node, but I have this notice:

> ERROR Database Connector   0:1        Execute failed: Could not create
>   connection to database: Invalid connection string
>   C:\Users\miPC\Desktop\DataBase1.IDB, reason: null or empty database
>   name in connection string

Comment: Hi and welcome, please take a look here and edit your question -> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: IDB is unusual file extension for Firebird, are you sure it is it? Then, copy-paste your connection string here and show the window with your database settings. P.S. `Wikipedia on KNIME: A graphical user interface and use of JDBC allows assembly of nodes...`

Comment: Frankly, this is not a question about how to develop new computer program, so seems off-topic. Probably it is better suited at http://superuser.com or maybe http://dba.stackexchange.com P.S. however even there the question would need details to be useful.

Comment: Please show all relevant information, including configuration or code used, full exception stacktrace, etc. The error indicates that Jaybird hasn't received a database name as part of its connection information (or at least: it couldn't parse it out of the information provided, because you seemed to have passed **only** `C:\Users\miPC\Desktop\DataBase1.IDB` as the connection string, which means it is missing the host name.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest that you have used the following connection string:

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://C:\Users\miPC\Desktop\DataBase1.IDB
```

That is incorrect as it is missing the host name. The correct URL would be:

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/C:\Users\miPC\Desktop\DataBase1.IDB
```

Please consult the [Jaybird FAQ for valid URL formats](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#jdbc-urls-java.sql.drivermanager).